# Docker error : Cannot start service angular , listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4200 already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

There is nothing mounted on port 3000 and 4200 and i stopped all containers just in case also.
When i do docker-compose up i get this error

```
 ERROR: for angular  Cannot start service angular: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint leapmotionreal_angular_1 (fd6858f87fb4db419407ae981758fdc8cdaa72d654db9b5aff91ccc8f6c4d1c8): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4200: bind: address already in use
```

And the front end is starts on port on 4200 but my backend doesnt and instead of logging it throws the mentioned error above.

My app structure looks like this .

```
~root 
   all angular files here in root
   Server folder with node js files > Dockerfile.yml(for node)
   docker-compose.yml
   Dockerfile.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  angular: 
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: ["4200:4200"]

  express: 
    build: 
      context: ./Server/
      dockerfile: ./Server/Dockerfile
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
```

Dockerfile for angular

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/client

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/client

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/client

RUN npm cache verify && npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/client

EXPOSE 4200:4200

CMD ["ng","serve"]
```

Dockerfile for node js app(my Server folder)

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/server

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/server

RUN npm cache verify && npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/server

EXPOSE 3000:3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `EXPOSE` instruction is:

```
EXPOSE <port> [<port>/<protocol>...]
```

Just change your docker files to use:

```
EXPOSE 4200
```

and

```
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: when we run a container like - p H:C like H being the host port and the C being the containers port ?

Comment: even the above mentioned answer gives the same error and runs only angular on 4200 like previosuly did.

Answer (score 0):

check for any container running in backgroupd " docker ps -a " and kill that container and also search for pid running for port 3000
and you might using multiple ports in your code like "console.log('listening on 3000')" not sure.

Comment: In the first line of the question i clearly said there is nothing mounted on those ports , i check them on browser and already stopped all the containers.

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about your setup. But I suggest some troubleshooting if u get time give a try.